# When cloning git repo under Windows I get "error: unable to create file <file>... (Is a directory)"

Tags: windows, git, msysgit

```
Z:\>git clone git://github.com/kennethreitz/httpbin.git
Cloning into 'httpbin'...
remote: Counting objects: 1073, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (401/401), done.
remote: Total 1073 (delta 672), reused 1045 (delta 651)
Receiving objects: 100% (1073/1073), 114.42 KiB | 128 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (672/672), done.
error: unable to create file httpbin/templates/... (Is a directory)
```

git version 1.8.0.msysgit.0, Windows Vista SP2 x64

What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the path where you clone is empty ?

Comment: @SimonBoudrias Yes. It looks like the problem is only with this specific repo...

Comment: And, is the path in question is more than 180 characters ? (if I remember correctly, it can't be more than 180 char on windows) -edit: Just taked a look at the repo and this is not the case... I hope someone will have an answer for you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the trouble is this file here in you repo: https://github.com/kennethreitz/httpbin/blob/master/httpbin/templates/...

`...` is not a valid filename under windows

In order to get the repo, clone without checking out files (with `-n` flag):

`git clone -n git://repo`

Then you could use a `sparse-checkout` to get all file but `...`, or you could only `git checkout` file you actually need.

Comment: I think you might be right. I could swear I cloned this repo successfully recently and this file is 1 year old...

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost I added commands to clone without checking out files