# Git clone unable to create file

Tags: git, git-clone

Trying to clone a remote git repository (bare), I get several errors like the following, after which git stops.

```
error: unable to create file frozen/email/lamson/mymailserver/run/queue/mark.name/cur/1361115664.1929_1.vps-pool-55:2,S (Invalid argument)
```

It's okay if I have to remove these files, but I can't find a way to do that if I can't clone.

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040577/when-cloning-git-repo-under-windows-i-get-error-unable-to-create-file-file

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess you're probably trying to do the clone on a Windows machine.  Windows doesn't allow filenames to use the `:` character.

From the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255), except for the following:
>
> - The following reserved characters:
>
>   - < (less than)
>   - > (greater than)
>   - : (colon)
>   - " (double quote)
>   - / (forward slash)
>   - \ (backslash)
>   - | (vertical bar or pipe)
>   - ? (question mark)
>   - * (asterisk)
> - Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII *NUL* character.
> - Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1 through 31, except for alternate data streams where these characters are allowed. For more information about file streams, see [File Streams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
> - Any other character that the target file system does not allow.

To work around this problem, you will probably need to clone on a non-windows system and correct the offending filenames.  Maybe some of the windows experts out there will have a better solution.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 12 (and the file was created on another Ubuntu)

Comment: Hmm - that's a bit strange, then.  Can you show some more context from the error log?

Comment: This (for several files) is all the console shows. However, your solution (cloning to a non-bare repository on another machine and resolving the problem there) worked!

Comment: Were you using a filesystem that can't handle one of those characters?

Comment: I can't find a list, but I think that's it!

Answer (score 3):

I'm cross-referencing my answer, as it also applies here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34515900/1012586

Yet instead of

```
*
!kickstarter/parsers/data/kickstarter/campaigndetails/*
```

you'd need something like

```
*
!frozen/email/lamson/mymailserver/run/queue/mark.name/cur/*
```

in your `.git/info/sparse-checkout`

Answer (score 0):

`git` will refuse to overwrite existing files. Try again, cloning into an empty directory.