# Git pull fails on invalid file characters

Tags: git

I have a problem with `Git` and pulling to master to update changes pushed to our production before branching again. There are a few files in production which happen to have `?` characters in them (JPG files). My local development runs on Windows and ofcourse when I pull from master I get error warnings:

```
error: unable to create file path/11891260_890522744361576_7814670597608320573_n.jpg?oh=4568ac0fd135cfcb57d48d4a78da8f8c&oe=56E71477 (Invalid arguments)
```

I cannot update my master branch without pulling and I cannot complete it when this happens. Is there no way around this except delete those files from production or tell Git to ignore them?

Comment: I think you'll have to resort to Linux, something like a live USB, a VM or Docker maybe?

Comment: Did you check the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097568/git-pull-error-unable-to-create-file-invalid-argument