# Git Unable to index file - Adding files failed

Tags: git

[image]I am running into a GIT issues I have never seen before and am looking for help at this point. Whenever I try and commit 1 specific file it fails with the error above.

I have tried removing the file from the directory, copying it, deleting the original and putting the new file back in.

It only seems to be happening for this one file and I am unsure why.

Comment: Here are some things you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097568/git-pull-error-unable-to-create-file-invalid-argument/26097902

Comment: The `EINVAL` error is rather mysterious. What OS are you using? (Based on pathnames, it looks like some Windows variant. I don't *use* Windows myself but it would make sense to look for what Windows file systems return EINVAL, and why.)

Comment: @torek It is windows 10

Comment: Hm, the main source of EINVAL on write on Windows 10 seems to be a file that exceeds 4 GB in size. Is that one file super-huge? (The EINVAL would occur during the zlib compression phase, so it would have to compress to a file that exceeds the 4 GiB limit.)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a permissions issue with the file.

Comment: All other files in that directory work, but this file doesnt seem too which I created and saved myself, but I will double check.

Answer (score 0):

Try erasing the .git/objects/*** (the one file only) and then commiting again

Comment: Not the entire database... just that one file!

Comment: I looked in that directory but was unsure of which one to delete since its also like 1a, 2f, etc EDIT: Oh wait I see now from the error

Comment: I recomend saving the file elsewhere as backup just in case. It is a good practice.