# In Quiqr on Windows, I can't checkout my site from git, other OS's work correctly

Tags: git

I'm trying to checkout a website from git with Quiqr on Windows. In the log console I get the error message:

```
"Clone error ...": Error: child exited with code 1
```

When I try to run embgit from the PowerShell I get a more complete error message:

```
Enumerating objects: 2933, done.
Counting objects: 100% (947/947), done.
Compressing objects: 100% (500/500), done.
Total 2933 (delta 437), reused 826 (delta 384), pack-reused 1986
error: open C:\Users\Administrator\Quiqr\temp\siteFromGit: is a directory
```

The same checkout with Quiqr on Linux or Mac gives no problems at all. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a file in your git-repository which has a name which is not allowed on Windows. E.g. `\` or `...`. Quiqr will fail to checkout on Windows. Try to find and remove the wrongly named files.

This is answered here too: [When cloning git repo under Windows I get "error: unable to create file <file>... (Is a directory)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040577/when-cloning-git-repo-under-windows-i-get-error-unable-to-create-file-file)

Comment: If it it answer *there*, it is a duplicate

Comment: this question is specially about Quiqr and not about git on windows.